# SQL: How to Transform rows to column in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Here is table structure, and sample data

```
create table #tmp ( Id int, Name varchar(100))
insert into #tmp (Id,Name)
Values (1,'Add')
insert into #tmp (Id,Name)
Values (2,'Update')

insert into #tmp (Id,Name)
Values (3,'Delete')
```

and expected result should be.

```
Add  Update  Delete
===  ======  ======
1    2       3
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways that you can transform the data from rows into columns.

If your database has a `PIVOT` function, then you could use the following code to pivot the data:

```
select [Add], [Update], [Delete]
from
(
  select id, name
  from #tmp
) src
pivot
(
  max(id)
  for name in ([Add], [Update], [Delete])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8a16/5).

Or you could use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select 
  max(case when name = 'Add' then id end) [Add],
  max(case when name = 'Update' then id end) [Update],
  max(case when name = 'Delete' then id end) [Delete]
from #tmp
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8a16/7)

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
SELECT [Add], [Update], [Delete]
    FROM (select * from #tmp) up 
        PIVOT (sum(id) FOR Name IN ([Add], [Update], [Delete])) AS pvt
```